# Javascript file input

Tags: javascript, file-io

I am trying to make a JS program using a text file on the client side. The thing is that it was difficult to find out how to do such a basic functionality because it is not a desired feature. I want to open a text file which is not in the local directory of a user but in the directory with the html file. So, what I want is the JS version of this code (which is in python)

```
# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")
fo.write( "Python is a great language.\nYeah its great!!\n");

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file with [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (as a result of a user selecting files) but fortunately **we can't modify client's or server's files with JavaScript in client side** (there is no `FileWriter()`). To do that, you should upload the file to the server (through [Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) or a [simple html form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)) and modify it with server side code.